# How do I get iOS to respect a manifest file for a web app that's already installed?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a web app that many users have added to their home screen. This works in **standalone** mode thanks to `apple-mobile-web-app-capable=true`. However, in recent versions of iOS, new pages break out of standalone and open in safari with header etc.

To fix this I've added a manifest with *Scope* set. This works and pages now open in *standalone* mode.

However, the only way I can get iOS to respect the manifest file is to delete the home screen icon and do the 'add to home screen' again. Even though it fetches the new page with the manifest meta tag in it, it never requests the manifest unless it's being installed (added to the home screen). Is there a way to force the manifest read?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? It seems to me that a manifest will never be read unless re-added to home screen.

Comment: No I never did manage to find a workaround. I hoped that it would get fixed as Apple improved their manifest file support.